# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float' when trying to change values

Tags: python

Im trying to write code that checks a list for a value < 0 and if there is one, replace it with 0. Whenever i write my if statement, i get the error in the title, I know its the fact im trying to compare i with 0 but i just cant figure out how to properly get this if statemtnt to work.

```
import random
cvalues=[]

for i in range(50):
  cvalues.append(random.randrange(0,16))

float_cvalues=[float(i) for i in cvalues]
final_cvalues=["{0:.2f}".format(i) for i in float_cvalues]


nvalues=[]
nvalues=[.4*i-.8 for i in float_cvalues]
float_nvalues=[float(i) for i in nvalues]
nvalues_changed=["{0:.2f}".format(i)for i in nvalues]

for i in nvalues_changed:
  if(i < 0):
    i=0
  else:
    i=i

test=list(zip(final_cvalues,nvalues_changed))
print(test)
```

Comment: whenever i add in i=float(i) before the if statement, it doenst change any of the values in the list that is less than 0

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `if i < 0: i = 0; else: i = 0`? It seems that you want to make all values to be 0?

Comment: Woops the last one is supposed to be i=i. Basically what im trying to do is check that if i in the list is less than 0, change it to 0 else keep it the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your code is jumping between `str` and `float`. If you want to round your numbers to two decimal places, use `round()`, don't convert it to string.

Anyways, here's your code, although admittedly, shortened:

```
import random

float_cvalues = [round(float(random.randrange(0, 16)), 2) for _ in range(50)]
nvalues = [round(float(.4 * i - .8), 2) for i in float_cvalues]

changed_nvalues = [0 if i < 0 else i for i in nvalues]

test = list(zip(float_cvalues, changed_nvalues))

print(test)
```

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it. I am supposed to report my variables to 2 places, hence why i was trying to use floats without rounding